# C++ library will not build because unresolved symbols and externals after upgrade to VS2015

Tags: c++, visual-c++, linker

I have a c++ library that was originally built (and will still build on an older machine which uses VS2008). We have not had to touch it since and have been able to just use the compiled .dll file over the past years.

However, recently, I tried to load the source code (by opening the solution file) in my new environment for the first time. My new environment is VS2015 update 3. When I first loaded the solution file, VS2015 did pop up a message that it would need to update my project files. It did that with no errors or warnings (that I could see).

However, I cannot build the projects. Please note, NO code has been changed yet so I can only believe that something was broken when opening/upgrading for VS2015. The errors I am getting are a ton of Linker errors for unresolved symbols and externals.

[image: Here are the errors]

After some reading, I did make sure that the .lib that it seems to be complaining most is referenced in my project, added to the project properties in the linker settings AND that the VC++ directory where the .lib file is located is specified in the properties as well. As a test, I purposely removed these settings and the errors changed to "File not found" so I know those settings are correct, so I put them back in. However, these 136 errors still exist with unresolved symbols and references.

NOTE: I don't have the source code for the .lib file, I don't believe. Also, I tried to make sure it is building against Win32 or x86 just to make sure it isn't that.

Not sure what else to try and have been searching for a while. Thanks[image: ![File is referenced in project]][2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WYFkO.jpg)[[image: file is added to linker in project properties]][3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uj0ba.jpg)

Comment: "I don't have the source code for the .lib file, I don't believe" - you're out of luck, that is where the problem lies. You can hack in your own implementations/stubs for the missing functions... but the best is to get the vendor to rebuild the .lib with 2015.

Comment: Try to add to linker legacy_stdio_definitions.lib . Check it here https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb531344.aspx#BK_CRT for more details

Comment: @Niall what would be the issue in the lib library? If that is the issue, I don't understand why if it works in the old VS2008 environment and was not changed or re-compiled when it was referenced in VS2015. How can simply opening the solution in VS2015 break code in the compiled lib file?

Comment: Roughly, static library format is tied to the compiler version. They are not portable between versions. A .lib file built with VS2008 can only be used with VS2008.

Comment: The lib is expecting the symbols to be there when everything is linked together. Those expected symbols are no longer there in the new version because of changes in the runtime.  In general, when linking C++ libraries, you must match the compiler and compiler options used to build the lib and the rest of the code.